# Canada transit visa passport submission, applicable visa application centre fees and biometric fees

Tags: canada, transit-visas

I had applied online for a Transit visa. Will be flying from US to India and back with probably 3-4 hour transit each way.

I had received a response to send my passport to finalize processing. I live in Phoenix. I believe the passport I will be sending my passport to the Los Angeles office Visa Processing Center as that's the closest one.

Questions:

1. I need to send a payment for processing my passport. Could someone please let me know the exact amount i need to send? Someone in this link( [Canadian Transit Visa - Passport Delivery Fee](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61583/canadian-transit-visa-passport-delivery-fee)) mentioned as 19.90 + 17.30 = 27.20$. First of all the math is wrong: 19.90 + 17.30 is 37.20. Also, in this link: https://www.vfsglobal.ca/Canada/USA/Service_and_Service_Charge.html it mentions the the 17.30$ fee as assisted service fee per form. I didn't take any assistance from them. The transit visa is supposed to be free and i filled it online myself.
2. In the TT consent form, there is a section for biometrics.  Should I say I need biometrics or not? Even for a transit visa do we need biometrics? Would my processing take a longer time if I mention yes to biometrics ? Whats the average processing time to get my passport back after submission of my passport? Also in the link share above, someone mentioned i need to send two copies of TT consent form. Their website doesn't mention anything about send two copies.
3. For the Pre-paid shipping label, what should I use for the From details?
4. For the cashier check or money order, who should I make it out to?

Comment: Did you talk to the office that is processing your visa about this?

Comment: Their office have only automated responses and no option to speak to a representative. I've sent an email and have been waiting for a response. So reaching out to the community for answers if anyone has been through this nightmare of an experience of getting a Canada transit visa, with such long processing times, all for a 3 hour layover that too in the same terminal in Vancouver. The transit without visa program doesn't apply to me.

Comment: Where were you instructed to send your passport? Did you receive this response by email? What did it say?

Comment: The response can as a pdf sent to my online account. All it said was they required my passport to finalize processing my application. Apart from the general passport requirements, it said to find out where to send my passport, visit this website: https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/account/where-submit-passport.html  For US residents, we could send it to embassy in Canada or to either NY or LA Visa Application Center. LA is the closest to me for fastest return I'd believe.

Comment: I am in the same boat and it seems for transit visa only first portion of consent form is to be signed. Also, there is no need to send money order since https://www.vfsglobal.ca/Canada/usa/Service_and_Service_Charge.html mentions the following.

"If you do not need to provide biometrics and you are submitting your passport, documents, or both at the VAC, the Package Transmission fee will apply."

This is further confirmed by the below section.

"How to pay applicable fee to TT Services:

It seems to suggest, the fee is only for submission directly at VAC but not for mail.

Comment: Yes, I sent 19.90$ as money order as transmission fee to Los Angeles VAC. Seemed quicker and cheaper that way instead of sending it to Canada. Got back the passport within a week after sending it to them.